# lines, where the last value for $6 = 0?

Tags: awk

How do I print all lines, where the last value for the line and print $6 = 0?

```
snap --list --all | awk '{print $1, $2, $3, $6}'
```

Example of desired output. Notice the last character on each line is 0 (ZERO). These would be the only lines I wish to see.... >>>

```
VDC-NIM-VMFS-SOFTWARE VDC-NIM-VMFS-ITNI-DEFAULT-Weekly-2018-09-11::06:50:00.000 1048576 0
VDC-NIM-VMFS-SOFTWARE VDC-NIM-VMFS-ITNI-DEFAULT-Daily-2018-09-11::06:45:00.000 1048576 0
VDC-NIM-VMFS-SOFTWARE VDC-NIM-VMFS-ITNI-DEFAULT-Daily-2018-09-10::06:45:00.000 1048576 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a condition to the `awk` commands

```
snap --list --all | awk '$6 == 0 {print $1, $2, $3, $6}'
```

Comment: Holy fish nuggets Bat Man, that seems to work! Thank you RalfFriedl!